# Gas Line? Vent Line attached to valve?

Tags: natural-gas

So moved into house, has gas for furnace and dryer. It seems that this is a gas line for the range, what I do not understand is the smaller pipe leaving the valve and off behind the wall. could it close loop or just vent? Havent tried to pill out from wall, it is an exterior wall Brick home, does not protrude to the outside.
Has electric range, but if this is gas the new range will be gas.
Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: In my neighborhood, all the houses built in the 50s have gas heat & hot water but all-electric kitchens. When I redid my kitchen I put in a gas cooktop which was easy because kitchen right above room with furnace/hot water heater. Some split level homes in the same neighborhood have no basement under the kitchen and can't (practically speaking) put gas in the kitchen. So having the pipe right there is fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

The flare fitting seems to indicate that it is gas supply tubing that leads to an appliance of some sort. It must lead to a gas dryer, gas cooker, gas grill, gas water heater, or gas fireplace (or did at one time). The valve is OFF, so there should be no harm disconnecting the old line and using the line to supply whatever you want; obviously whatever it leads (or led) to is not in service.

Comment: thank you, that is where my thoughts were as well, I wonder if previous owner didnt just have  a preference for electric range. I appreciate the fast reply.

Comment: Hmm yes, but I'm still curious as to where it goes. I would bet a dollar that, since it's an outside wall, it went to a gas grill.